# I required a script to add a CBERS4A layer in QGIS from Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

Currently I have a script to add Sentinel2 images from gee. I required an easy way to add cbers4a images in a QGIS project. The following script is used to add S2 images:

```
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map
images = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterDate('2022-09-06','2022-09-25').filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',99)

filter = images.median()
Map.addLayer(filter,{'min':[600,700,600],'max':[5400,5100,5000],'gamma':1.4,'bands':['B4','B3','B2']})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no CBERS images in Earth Engine.  You would have to upload your own copies.

Comment: thanks! so the best way to add cbers images in QGIS is by CBERS4ADownloader plugin?